# NodeJS external session not returning value

Tags: external-calls

I have setup my `NodeJS` session and performed the following test. I evaluate the following commands in `ExternalLanguage` cells.

```
test = 1+1
```

returns 2

```
test
```

returns 2

But when I try to get the value of the following builtin variable

```
global
```

Instead of returning its value, I get the following error

```
Failure["NodeJSError",<|
    "FailureCode" -> "Error",
    "MessageTemplate" -> "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded",
    "Traceback" -> "..."
|>]
```

Please help me fix this. Could be because the output is too large. Btw it works fine on the nodejs console.

Note: I am using `NodeJS` version `10.16.0 LTS` and `Mathematica` version `12.0.0`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `global` is already defined in the `ExternalEvaluate` environment. The `ExternalEvaluate` sets up a "context" to evaluate code within, and that context gets these variables defined within it:

```
ctx.require = require;
ctx.global = global;
ctx.process = process;
ctx.Buffer = Buffer;
ctx.console = console;
```

You can see how this is implemented in `Applications/Wolfram Desktop.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Components/ExternalEvaluate_NodeJS/
Resources/eval.js`.

I expect this is not strictly a bug but rather an implementation detail.

Unfortunately, it appears you're not able to use `global` as a user-defined name in `ExternalEvaluate`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know that `global` is a restricted variable in `NodeJS` and provides the same information as `JavaScript` running in browser does for variable `window`. The problem is I want to get the value of this variable not assign something to it. Its value is a huge `JSON` containing all the function and objects available in the current environment. But it is not coming out of `ExternalEvaluate` because of some call stack size issue.

Comment: Aha, I did misunderstand your question. Unfortunately I won't be able to help for the next few weeks - I wish you good luck in finding your answer!